# Android Nougat: after setResult and finish is called, Application minimized

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

My application is minimized in Android 7.0 i.e. Nougat device when I use the following code snippet:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
/*if (getParent() == null) {
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
} else {
    getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
}*/
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

Please note that: below Nougat i.e. in Lollipop and Marshmallow, the above code is working fine.

Any ideas, how to solve this issue for Nougat. Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect this code snippet to do in android nougat?

Comment: `finish()` destroys the current activity, returning control to the activity that preceded it. What activity is starting this one, and what is that activity doing in `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: Yes, my implementation is like: if user stays on a Activity for 3 mins, then this activity which has the above code opens and if user provides proper password then just finish this activity and opens the Underlying Activity which he was there for 3 mins.

Comment: in `onActivityResult()` I am just checking the `RESULT_OK`. But the problem is control is not transferred to the `onActivityResult()` of the Underlying Activity after `setResult()` and `finish()`.